# Xcode: Why doesn't this code work for saving UITextField using NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I have an UITextField inside an UITableViewCell. What I want't is for the app to save the text the user inputs. I've tried by making the UITextField call a action with this code:

```
    [TextField addTarget:self action:@selector(saveTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

However this action that it load doesn't work correctly:

```
- (IBAction)saveTextField:(id)sender {

NSString *TextFieldString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:TextField.text];
[TextField setText:TextFieldString];
NSUserDefaults *UserSettings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[UserSettings setObject:TextField forKey:@"TextField"];    }
```

When I exit the UITextField by trying to hide the keyboard by clicking "Done" I get this message:

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument
```

and nothing happens in the app.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with: thanks for your effort and time :)

Turns out the problem wasn't with the code that saves and loads it. The problem was that I only created one UITextfield which I then put into every UITableViewCell and that was the problem. So I created individual UITextFields for every UITableViewCells and that fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I use the exact same functionality in one of my apps, and this is the code I use:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject: textField.text forKey:@"TextField"];`

Basically, I don't think the first two lines in your saveTextField method where you alloc a new string are necessary.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... when I dismiss the Viewcontroller by using dismissModalViewControllerAnimated and then present it again using presentMoadlViewController it's gone.... any idea?

Comment: Yes -- if you don't synchronize the defaults, they won't immediately save. Call this after settings: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]`